# Android Studio - XML Skewed Layout after Git

Tags: android, xml, git, android-studio, android-manifest

After importing my project via Git, the hierarchy of my project changed only slightly with all the correct folders and files still intact. However, my layout changed from:

[image]

to this:

[image]

If you notice every XML element is larger on the second run. I've run it on 3 different devices (All API: 21) and achieved the same result. Below is the XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/win8_orange"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:backgroundTintMode="src_atop">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/usernameText"
        android:background="@color/AntiqueWhite"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="141dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/user_name"
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/usernameText"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/usernameText"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/usernameText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:id="@+id/passWord"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/usernameText"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/usernameText"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/passwordText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/passwordText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/passWord"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/passWord"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@color/AntiqueWhite"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passwordText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/skip_text"
        android:id="@+id/skipLoginButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@color/win8_orange"
        android:textColor="@color/win8_red"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the Android Manifest **(Side note: why doesn't the API level need to be specified here with Android Studio?)**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.name" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.app.name.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.app.name"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: To address your side note, I believe Android studio now specifies api-level information in the gradle files instead of the manifest.

Comment: Ok. I'll research Gradle then

Answer (score 0):

It's all about how you add the Android Studio project to Git. After adding it to GitHub the right way, the project became seamless.

Here's a video that's rather talkative, but describes how to set that up using Version Control: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ldmc757EXaE